# Dynamically set binding in data-bind

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In knockout.js we have a basic example with the most basic text binding:

```
Today's message is: <span data-bind="text: myMessage"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        myMessage: ko.observable() // Initially blank
    };
    viewModel.myMessage("Hello, world!"); // Text appears
</script>
```

This is straight from tutorial http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html
What if I want to have a variable that defines the actual binding property. That could look something like this:

```
Today's message is: <span data-bind="myBinding: myMessage"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        myMessage: ko.observable(), // Initially blank
        myBinding: ko.observable(), // Initially blank
    };
    viewModel.myMessage("text");
    viewModel.myMessage("Hello, world!"); // Text appears
</script>
```

Above code is obviously wrong, but what would the correct case be?

I was looking into some stuff like ko.applyBindingsToNode ( [Can I dynamically bind element inside custom binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109455/can-i-dynamically-bind-element-inside-custom-binding) ) but the Google FU is totally failing me this time, because most of the thing I find is applying bindings to dynamically built elements and not apllying dynamic binding types dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an observable as a custom binding type.  Observable's are for storing data.

You can get the functionality you want by using either a [Custom Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) or a [Computed Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).  Personally, if this is something special that you need one time, then use a Computed Observable.  Otherwise, use a custom binding.

Comment: Bingo! I figured it out with computed obsevables :)